# swift UITableViewCell with protocol issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

I have a protocol

```
protocol AttibuteValueCellProtocol {
    func set(attribute: String, value: String)
}
```

And in my tableView's datasource method I want my cell to confirm to this protocol. In objective-c I could do that, but in SWIFT it gives the error when I try to use `as? UITableViewCell<AttibuteValueCellProtocol>`. In objective-C it always worked if I do (`(UITableViewCell<AttibuteValueCellProtocol> *)cell`)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell<AttibuteValueCellProtocol>
}
```

What can I replace it with?

P.S.
Error looks like this http://take.ms/OHRA3

**I don't need extension**  , because when I deque cell , it will be CustomCell (and CustomCell conforms to Protocol), but this class can use different cell identifiers so this class shouldn't know about the cell class name and not every cell conforms to AttibuteValueCellProtocol , this class has to know that we have cell that conforms to protocol AttibuteValueCellProtocol

I Objective-C I can do that and it will compile (I understand that it will not work because view1 doesn't conform to protocol, but it's easy to create proper view and it will work,here I just give an example) :

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)testMethod;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *viewForProtocolJustToShow = (UIView<TestProtocol> *)view1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: How does the error look like? I suppose you need to write an `extension` of `UITableViewCell`, where you actually implement that protocol.

Comment: instead of writing in deque line use `cell.delegate = self`,where delegate is protocol type

Comment: @Jack , I need to implement the same as in objective-c , I want my cell to conform to protocol, not cell delegate

Comment: Just delete `<AttibuteValueCellProtocol>` from this line and later use `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: my cell don't have delegate , so cell.delegate will give an error

Comment: It should be enough if you do `as? AttibuteValueCellProtocol`.

Comment: You want to have your cell as Protocol type?

Comment: @PaulT. If it is a `CustomCell` already, just cast it to that instead of a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Why don't you cast your different cells to different Cell class??

Comment: Because I use Factory Method pattern where I need to use protocols

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

As the error says, `UITableViewCell` is not a generic type. With this syntax you are confusing *conforming to a protocol* with *setting the type of a generic object*.

**Solution 1: Extensions**

To get a `UITableViewCell` that conforms to the `AttibuteValueCellProtocol`, you can use an extension:

```
extension UITableViewCell: AttibuteValueCellProtocol {
  // implementation of AttibuteValueCellProtocol requirements goes here
}
```

You will have to implement the `AttibuteValueCellProtocol` methods as Swift (and Objective-C) have no way of knowing how they should be defined.

**Solution 2: Subclass**

Extending the whole `UITableViewCell` class could create some strange side effects if you do not always want those extra methods. You can also just subclass `UITableViewCell` and implement the `AttibuteValueCellProtocol` protocol there:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, AttibuteValueCellProtocol {
  // implementation of AttibuteValueCellProtocol requirements goes here
}
```

And then, you can do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyTableViewCell
}
```

**Solution 3: Protocol**

You can also just check if the returned `UITableViewCell` conforms to a specific protocol:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyProtocol
}
```

Note that this will set cell to nil if it does not conform.

Comment: I don't need every cell to conform to AttibuteValueCellProtocol , but I need to be sure that my CELL will conform to this protocol, pls see my Edition in the answer

Comment: @PaulT. I just added a second solution, please take a look.

Comment: As I said before I don't need to know about MyTableViewCell class, only about UITableViewCell and that it conforms to Protocol, it was possible in objective-C

Comment: `UITableViewCell` does not conform to your `AttibuteValueCellProtocol`, and it *cannot* unless you tell it how to. This is also true in Objective-C. You mentioned that you have a `CustomCell` class, can you post the code for that?

Comment: I added the code at the bottom part of my answer how it works in Objective-C

Comment: @PaulT. Updated again, this should compile, but if the dequeued cell doesn't conform to the protocol, cell will just be nil (similar to the Objective-C example, which will crash if you do `[viewForProtocolJustToShow testMethod]` because UIView doesn't actually conform to the protocol)

Comment: it will compile, but  cell will not inheret UITableViewCell in this case, so I can't set background without using as? UITableViewCell one more time in a new line.

Comment: Do you have a CustomCell class? Why are you expecting the UITableViewCell to conform to the protocol?

Comment: I have CustomCell: UITableViewCell, AttibuteValueCellProtocol , CustomCell2: UITableViewCell, AttibuteValueCellProtocol, CustomCell3: UITableViewCell, AttibuteValueCellProtocol classes, but my data provider class don't know about exact class name, but he knows about Protocol they confirm

Comment: Okay, so you can create a base class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, AttributeValueCellProtocol, then have CustomCell1: CustomCell, CustomCell2: CustomCell.. and so on. Then you just cast to CustomCell and it will work as you expect.