# Can UITableViewCells be delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I am wondering if I can make a UITableViewCell conform to a protocol, and set the UITableViewCell as a delegate. The reason is, because I want some UITableViewCells to update when a certain value is changed in another class, and I am thinking of doing this with a protocol/delegate method. However, as of now, I have not been able to turn a UITableViewCell into a delegate successfully. Is it even possible?

This is the code I have so far:

**The protocol**

```
protocol UploadManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
  func taskWasUpdated(id: String, value: Double)
}
```

**Uploading Manager class**

```
public final class UploadingManager {
  static var uploadingTasks: Dictionary<String, Double> = [:]
  static weak var uploadDelegate: UploadManagerDelegate

  static func removeTask(id: String) {
    uploadingTasks.removeValue(forKey: id)
  }
  
  static func getTask(id: String) -> Double? {
    if uploadingTasks[id] == nil {
      return nil
    } else {
      return uploadingTasks[id]
    }
  }
  
  static func isUploading(id: String) -> Bool {
    return (uploadingTasks[id] != nil)
  }
  
  static func updateTask(id: String, completion: Double) {
    uploadingTasks[id] = completion
    uploadDelegate?.taskWasUpdated(id: id, value: completion)
  }
}
```

**Custom UITableViewCell class**

```
class TrackCell: UITableViewCell, UploadManagerDelegate {

...

override func awakeFromNib() {
  UploadingManager.uploadDelegate = self // Can I do this??
  super.awakeFromNib()
}

...

func taskWasUpdated(id: String, value: Double) {
  if(audioFile?.trackID == id) {
    activityIndicator.setProgress(Float(value), animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can set it in the cellForRow func in the UITableViewDelegate after you dequeue cell set the delegate `UploadingManager.uploadDelegate = cell`.
but I think it would be better to let the VC be the delegate here then the VC can update the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can conform as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43487804/651409).

But there are some cases which you must consider before doing it, for example:

1. All cells will be conforming same protocol so the activityIndicator progress update will always be same on all cells.
2. You require to update cell only when they are visible because of dequeueReusableCell

So, my recommendation is also same as @Hossam suggested in comment that update cell from VC (UploadingManager).